# Laravel 5.2: Trying to use ID from database to display image with corresponding name?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

For each entry in the database, there is a corresponding image whose file name is the same as the unique ID of that database entry, eg an entry with ID '4' has the header image title '4.png'. I want to display the relevant image to the entry currently displayed, but I can't quite get the code below to work:

```
$img = asset('images/header/' . $img_id . '.png');
```

I've verified that $img_id works, and the images are displayed when if I just use the direct path to them - ie 'images/header/4.png'.

Comment: are you checked your image path properly?

Comment: Where are you using `$img` ? If it's in a view, can you paste the final HTML generated when you view the source in your browser?

Comment: @Joseph because I'm using it as a background image, I'm storing it in $img and then in <style> tags, setting it as the background image.. The generated code results in: background-image: URL(http://localhost:8000/images/header/1.png);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code snippet seems to be ok. You should be using it in the view like:

```
<img src="<?= asset('images/header/' . $img_id . '.png') ?>">
```

Ideally you could opt for an accessor to deal with this. In your model, add this:

```
public function getImgAttribute()
{
    return '<img src="'. asset('images/header/' . $this->attributes['id'] . '.png') .'">';
}
```

Now you can use it in your views like `$model->img`.